# Nested multi column

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to make a table with slightly big rows to write my content in them, almost all rows are multirows.
i have used multirow but the content in a row overflows 
here is what i am trying to make

[image]

Comment: Would you mind supplying the TeX code of what you tried?

Comment: hope para mode setting may useful for you, e.g., \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}....}....\end{tabular}